# jQuery Fancybox enter-capture in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, fancybox

```
jQuery(document).keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        alert(1);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

I've got the above code. It works in all the major browsers. The problem is, when I open fancybox in Chrome, it stops working till it's closed. How can I work around this? It does work in all other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `keydown` instead ... and moving `preventDefault()` higher?

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(1);
        return false;
    }
});
```